# Fishbowl server - database error

Tags: mysql, database, connection, fishbowl

How to connect with database in fishbowl server. In PHP code, when I do login with the default credentials it shows me the database error.

Connect with Fishbowl Developer Hook

FbiMsgsRs statusCode="1004"

FbiMsgsRs= There is an error with database.

Comment: Please add some source code and error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: FbiMsgsRs statusCode="1004"